# LookAt Matrix Question - when are they equivalent

Tags: opengl, camera, coordinate-transformation

Could you please confirm or deny the following statements which I think are true?

1) Two LookAt matrices

```
 glLookAt(eye, center1, up)
```

and

```
 glLookAt(eye, center2, up)
```

are equivalent if `center1 - eye == k(center2 - eye)` for some positive k.

2) Tho LookAt matrices are never equivalent if their `eye` vector is different.

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate the matrices produces by gluLookAt from those input vectors, subtract them and test for them being equal to 0?

Comment: @datenwolf, for ALL possible matrices? :P

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz: I don't see where the problem is. You just have to put those values into the matrix gluLookAt builds and subtract them from each other. eye is a constant, center1 is arbitrary, so `center2 = (center1-eye)/k + eye`. You put thost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are equivalent if center1 - eye == k(center2 - eye) for some positive k.

That is correct. The direction vector is calculated from center - eye, and then normalized, so the length doesn't matter if the direction is the same.

Beware though that there could be very slight numerical differences in the resulting matricies because of rounding. For all practical purposes though, the matricies are the same.